# Setting EventQuery.Uri resets the EventQuery state

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

This works:

```
public override bool GetAppointments(CalendarModel calendar, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    foreach (var googcal in _settings.Calendars.Where(googcal => googcal.Selected)) {
        var eventQuery = new EventQuery {
            Uri = new Uri(googcal.ProviderData),
            // Passed in startDate/endDate are inclusive
            StartTime = startDate.Date,
            EndTime = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)
        };
        var eventFeed = Service.Query(eventQuery);
        foreach (EventEntry appt in eventFeed.Entries) {
...
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This does not:

```
public override bool GetAppointments(CalendarModel calendar, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    foreach (var googcal in _settings.Calendars.Where(googcal => googcal.Selected)) {
        var eventQuery = new EventQuery {
            // Passed in startDate/endDate are inclusive
            StartTime = startDate.Date,
            EndTime = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1),
            Uri = new Uri(googcal.ProviderData)
        };
        var eventFeed = Service.Query(eventQuery);
        foreach (EventEntry appt in eventFeed.Entries) {
...
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the first case `Event.Query.StartTime` and `EndTime` are set correctly, as expected.

In the second case they are uninitialized (`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`).

The only difference is the order of the properties in the object initializer.

For grins, I did the order like this:

```
// Passed in startDate/endDate are inclusive
StartTime = startDate.Date,
Uri = new Uri(googcal.ProviderData),
EndTime = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)
```

and sure enough `EndTime` is correct, but `StartTime` is uninitalized.

This makes no sense to me. How could it be?

Comment: Maybe problem is somewhere else. Order doesn't affect my object initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Object initializers *just set properties*. Any side-effects of setting one property before another will be visible just as if you'd written it out longhand:

```
var tmp = new EventQuery();
tmp.StartTime = startDate.Date;
tmp.EndTime = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
tmp.Uri = new Uri(googcal.ProviderData);
var eventQuery = tmp;
```

In this case, I suspect that some internal state is *added to* by setting `StartTime`/`EndTime` but *reset* by setting `Uri`.

EDIT: Okay, I've now found [the relevant code](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/feedquery.cs).

`EventQuery` derives from `FeedQuery`. Setting the `Uri` on `FeedQuery` calls `ParseUri` which in turn sets all of the internal properties.

Basically, this sort of thing will always happen when you have inter-related properties. Imagine you had a `Size` property of a type which reflected a width and a height which could also be set independently - you'd be able to write:

```
var foo = new Foo {
    Width = 100,
    Size = new Size(200, 50),
    Height = 20
};
```

and end up with a size of 200x20. Basically it all makes sense when you understand that `Uri` is a property representing the complete query URI, not just the stem.

Comment: Yep, your suspicion is correct Jon.  See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

It is amazing how the act of asking a question on Stack Overflow can help you understand what is going on.  I'm leaving this question here so that anyone else who comes across this will know what's going on...I can't be the only person who will have this problem.

In the Google Calendar API V2, the .NET library, which I am using here has what I think is a bug in the `EventQuery` class.

Specifically, setting `Uri` has side-effects on the object. Specifically, it causes the `StartTime` and `EndTime` properties to be initialized.

I've fixed my code by doing this:

```
var eventQuery = new EventQuery(googcal.ProviderData) {
    StartTime = startDate.Date, 
    EndTime = endDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)
};
```

IOW, setting the Uri in the constructor.

Comment: It would have helped if you'd said you were using v2 before - I've been looking through the v3 code.

Comment: You can set it in the constructor - or you could just set it before setting the other properties, as per your first example. I'd probably pass it into the constructor though. I don't think it's a bug per se, although it could be more clearly documented.

Comment: It's not a bug, you are just using it incorrectly. You set *either* Uri *or* the rest of properties. Uri is not ever stored. It gets broken down to components and each time it's requested it's reassembled back. So if you set URI first and then you change StartTime and EndTime when you query URI again it will be different. It will get reassembled from components two of which are StartTime and EndTime you just provided.